# Converting the image to grayscale vs reading it directly as a grayscale image

Tags: opencv, colors

Is there any difference between reading an image directly as a grayscale

```
imread(path, CV_LOAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

and reading it as a BGR and then converting it to grayscale?

```
cvtColor(src,dst, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

or the first approach just uses the second one?

Comment: According imread [Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) if  the flag CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE is set, imread() always convert image to the grayscale one

Comment: But does it read it as a BGR and then convert it to grayscale using the same functionality that cvtColor uses? or does it use a different one?

Comment: Yes imread() doing that internally by looking the flag, see imread source https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp